# Analytical solution of the Fokker-Planck equation for a damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, differential-equations, open-quantum-systems

I was having some trouble while trying to understand the solution for the Fokker-Planck equation for a damped harmonic oscillator, as given in chapter-3 of the textbook "Statistical Methods for Quantum Optics, Vol-1" by Howard Carmichael. The equations of interest are equations (3.53), (3.54) and (3.55).
If we were to substitute equation (3.54) into (3.53), we get the following equation:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}\right)Y+\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\right)X=\left[\frac{\gamma}{2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y\right)+\frac{\gamma \bar{n}}{4} \left(\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^2}\right)\right]XY
\end{equation}
(Here, X is shorthand for X(x,t) and Y is shorthand for Y(y,t)).

Expanding the RHS of the above equation and grouping terms gives us:
\begin{equation}
\left[\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}\right)-\frac{\gamma}{2}\frac{\partial (xX)}{\partial x}-\frac{\gamma \bar{n}}{4}\frac{\partial^{2}X}{\partial x^{2}}\right]Y=-\left[\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\right)-\frac{\gamma}{2}\frac{\partial (xY)}{\partial x}-\frac{\gamma \bar{n}}{4}\frac{\partial^{2}Y}{\partial x^{2}}\right]X 
\end{equation}

At this point, it appears as if the author equated the terms in the square brackets to zero on both sides to get equations (3.55a) and (3.55b). Why does he do that? I feel that the more appropriate way to proceed would be to write:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{X}\left[\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}\right)-\frac{\gamma}{2}\frac{\partial (xX)}{\partial x}-\frac{\gamma \bar{n}}{4}\frac{\partial^{2}X}{\partial x^{2}}\right]=-\frac{1}{Y}\left[\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\right)-\frac{\gamma}{2}\frac{\partial (xY)}{\partial x}-\frac{\gamma \bar{n}}{4}\frac{\partial^{2}Y}{\partial x^{2}}\right]=f(t) 
\end{equation}
where f is some function of time alone.

Is there some way to show that our approaches are equivalent? If not, then is there any physical basis for not considering the more general equation that I got? That is, how do we know that his approach will give the right solution?

Thanks!